# Entity Framework Can't Save in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got a problem with the entity framework as it's my first time using it along with SQL server. I managed to successfully create an entity data model with an entity called EMP. EMP has ID, Name, and Salary as scalar properties. I then generated the database from the model, copy/pasted the resulting sddl into SQL server and created my database. I went back into VS 2010 express and tried adding some records into the database using the following code:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dataemp"].ConnectionString;
dataemp db = new dataemp(constr);

db.AddToEmps(Emp.CreateEmp(0, "john", "Informatique", "10000000 cfa"));
db.AddToEmps(Emp.CreateEmp(1, "johny greg", "finances", "100000000 cfa"));

db.SaveChanges();//i get the error here
Console.WriteLine(
  "*********Employee actuellement dans la database*********\n{0}",
  query.ToString());
```

As a result the compiler gives me an exception as if I didn't connect to the database or as if it couldn't access the database but it is displayed in the database explorer. One more point in the database explorer: I can't see the tables(EMPs) whereas in SQL Server I am able to see it as dbo.Emps.  Here is the exception the compiler shows me:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner ex ception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Emps'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStre am,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String res etOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,  Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Bo olean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Bo olean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnec tion connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapt er adapter)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapt er adapter)    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   entityCache)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\ITA
>   Final\documents\visual studio 2010\Project s\zut\zut\Program.cs:line
>   13

I have read many tutorials on entity framework and linq to entities. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `Invalid object name 'dbo.Emps'` Well, did you check to see if that exists?

Comment: yeah i did it exist in sql server but the visual c# database explorer doesnt show it at all i dont know what to do ;the file is the same the connection string points to

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right database? The message is crystal clear - Emps doesn't exist in the database you are connecting to

Comment: well i thought so too but it displays the same database name which is employee.mdf into visual c# and when i click on test connection it works

Comment: Referesh the server connection in sql server to check if dbo.emps exist. Or check if the underlying model class hasn't changed.

Comment: ok ill check it when i get back home. in the meantime can you direct me to a tutorial starting from creating a model and generating the database and add the records directly from c#? i mean a tutorial that shows how to create an emtpty database from the entity designer model to sql server and add records in it from c#? just to check if i wasnt wrong somewhere in the making of the database and the model

Comment: post your connection string

Comment: i ve to get back home to post it am in a cyber cafe

Comment: am going to get it please wait up guys

Comment: go through this links on connection strings:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761193/system-configuration-configurationmanager-connectionstrings-has-no-connection-st, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828060/c-sharp-configuration-manager-connectionstrings

Comment: i just ran home to get it here's the connection string:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings><add name="dataemp" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;D:\Users\ITA Final\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\employee.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: Try putting this in your onmodelcreating: modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

Comment: where will i find it the onmodelcreating?nevermind i found it on google ill go home and do as u said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are having a problem with something not existing in a database, which indicates bad connection, and given your connection string,

> connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model‌​1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string='Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Users\ITA
>   Final\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\employee.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect
>   Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"

where the actual connection string used by ADO is

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=&quot;D:\Users\ITAFinal\Documents\Visual Studio 
    2010\Projects\employee.mdf&quot;;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;
User Instance=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

I wonder why there's no `Initial Catalog` component to the connection string. You should determine the correct database within the MDF file to connect to, and include

```
Initial Catalog=MyDbName;
```

in the string. Immediately after the `Integrated Security=True;` piece will be a good place to put it.

Comment: very true what you said as it was autogenerated by visual studio i didnt bother modifying anything from it apart from the <add name="dataemp"> ill do it im pretty sure that s what i was missing thanks

Comment: @LilzVotcaLove happy to help, remember to upvote or mark correct!

Comment: i finally figured it out the real problem was that sql server saves the database into program files\microsoft sql server\mssql\...\data and Visual studio used the default file created by E.F which is stored in mydocuments now i just have to find out how to change sql server default saving locations

Answer (score 0):

The only way for this error to occur, is for the table to not exist in the database you're connecting to. The connection string you're using for the context cannot be correct. This could occur if the value of the connection string in the `Web` or `App` config files is wrong, **or** you're setting that connection string by hand and setting it wrong.

Comment: thnx i know that maybe ive not set the connection string to the real database i just posted the connection string above please have a look at it and tell me what is wrong i changed the add name to dataemp as it is the name ive set for the entity set container

Comment: @LilzVotcaLove, do you have a `<connectionStrings>` section in your configuration file? If so, do you have an `<add name="dataemp"...` in there?

Comment: yeah i do .here s the string   <configuration> <connectionStrings><add name="dataemp" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model‌​1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;D:\Users\ITA Final\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\employee.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings> </configuration>

Comment: does the model file has to have the same name as the database