# "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." - but only when publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6.1

I have an MVC5 / EF6.1 website that runs perfectly on my development machine using LocalDb.

However, when I publish this to an Azure Website with an Azure SQL Database, I get the following error when doing any database interaction:

`The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`

I've searched all over and can't find the reason that this happens on Azure.

The first file the stack trace points to is **IdentityModels.cs:45**

That contains the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

When I publish to Azure I've tested the connection string (comes back OK), and this is the Settings screen:

[image]

Any idea as to what is going on?

**UPDATE:**

If don't select `ApplicationDbContext` and instead select `DefaultConnection` it works, however I won't be able to use code first migrations. How can I get the `ApplicationDBContext` to work again?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem - I found my solution.

I had just upgraded **ASP Identity** to version 2.0.0 via Nuget, and when it installed the **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework** package it changed my publish settings and seperated the `AppliationDbContext` and the `DefaultConnectionString` and this is what caused the problem.

What I had to do was literally as easy as to change the following to my `ApplicationDbContext`

**ASP Identity 1.0.0**

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{

}
```

**ASP Identity 2.0.0**

```
// Set the throwIfV1Schema to false...
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{

}
```

I have no idea why this didn't affect my local development version, but it's solved my issue. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. I grappled with this issue all morning. I went through the same process as you followed. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: This worked for me too, although my see method didn't fire (which it does on my local dev machine). Any thoughts?

Comment: @JasonJames Are you 100% sure that you checked the "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)." checkbox when you published?

Comment: When I added the extra argument I didn't even see the context used for Identity in the list of available databases when I go to publish it. I still see the other context, but that doesn't have a seed method. However, the schema was only created when I first tried to access the tables, not during publishing.

Comment: @JasonJames It's hard to tell without seeing your project unfortunately, however if that context doesn't appear on the publish screen then something isn't set correctly. You should  try adding "throwIfV1Schema: false" onto both of your contexts. Then in theory they should appear on the publish screen and allow you to execute your migrations and seed method. Good luck! :)

Comment: It seems to only be a parameter if the context inherits from IdentityDbContext, and not DbContext, so I can't add it to both.

Comment: Thank you!  You helped resolve what was a very frustrating problem for me!

Answer (score -1):

I just unclick "execute code first migration" it worked.