# Issue with "update-data" in Package Manger Console

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I tried the "update-data" after adding a table yet an error

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

appeared instead.

It should have "Done" the "update-database " as builder in the Package Manger Console yet there's an issue. The video that I was learning from has the connection as only "." in the beginning while mine ".\SQLEXPRESS" I tried it both manually and Copy then paste:

```
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DotNET6;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please follow this article link and follow steps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865584/the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized-on-update-database?rq=2