# "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." Error in SQL bulkcopy upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, connection-string, sqlbulkcopy

I just created mvc 4 application,in that application I have function to upload Excel File to the database.

this is working fine in localhost .

But when I deploy in **IIS** and try to upload excel file.I'm getting following error

> *The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.*

These are the connection strings I'm using to upload excel files

```
<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source="000.000.00.00";Initial Catalog=AFFHEC_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="constr" connectionString="data source=000.000.0.000;Initial catalog=AFFHEC_DB;user id=**;password=*****;" />
<add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES';" />
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
```

This is the code for SQL bulk copy upload

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Student(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload1, tbl_hec_Programme programme)
    {

        try
        {
            string conString = string.Empty;
            //Upload and save the file


           if (Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength > 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    string excelPath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/"), Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);


                    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                                            conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);  
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    this.SetNotification("The file type submitted is invalid", NotificationEnumeration.Error);

                }

                try
                {

                   using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                    {
                        excel_con.Open();

                        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                        string query =    "SELECT " +
                                          "s1.HEC_ID, " +
                                          "s1.Student_Personal_ID, " +
                                          "s1.Student_Passport_Number, " +
                                          "s1.Student_ID_by_University, " +
                                          "s1.First_Name, " +


                         //    // join three tables
                        "FROM (((([Personal_Data$] as s1) " +
                        "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Enrolment_Data$] as s2 ON s1.HEC_ID = s2.HEC_ID) " +

                        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excel_con))
                        {
                            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                        }

                        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con,
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints |
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls |
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction |
                                                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity,
                                                        null))
                            {
                                //Set the database table name
                                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_HEI_student";

                                sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Student_Personal_ID", "Student_Personal_ID_CPR");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Student_Passport_Number", "Student_Passport_Number");
                                ................


                                con.Open();

                                try
                                {

                                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);

                                    int totalRowsAdded = dtExcelData.Rows.Count;


                                    UploadStatusWriter(User.Identity.GetUserId(), Status_type, Date_type);



                                    this.SetNotification("Student data successfully uploaded", NotificationEnumeration.Success);



                                    return RedirectToAction("StudentIndex", "HEI");





                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    this.SetNotification(ex.Message, NotificationEnumeration.Error);
                                    return RedirectToAction("Student", "Excel");
                                }
                                finally
                                {

                                    con.Close();


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.SetNotification(ex.Message, NotificationEnumeration.Error);
                    return RedirectToAction("Student", "Excel");
                }

            }

            else
            {
                this.SetNotification("Please select a file first and then click the submit button", NotificationEnumeration.Error);
                return RedirectToAction("Student", "Excel");

            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Student", "Excel");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code as well?

Comment: How do you query the db? [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007786/how-to-fix-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: We need to see the code where you are interacting with the Db and using a connection.

Comment: I just inserted whole code,

Comment: What line produces the exception?

Comment: No single error in localhost debug mode, getting above error once I deployed on IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. After many many researches I found we should do some configurations in IIS Deployment as well as Allow permissions for release folder.

Here those configurations

**Step 1**

1. Add a proper site name
2. "Content Directory" Chose correct path of your release folder
3. For the binding, "Type" give **https** or **http** , if you deploy in your machine for IP address give your machine IP address else server IP Address and find a proper port also.
4. For application pool keep it as **DefaultAppPool** for now

[image]

**Step 2**

Then go to Applications Pools Find your web site's application pool and change it to **ASP.NET v4.0** (if your .NET framework 4.0)

[image]

**Step 3**

Go to your web application main panel find Directory Browsing (under IIS section)

[image]

**Step 4**

Double click directory browsing and **enable** it

[image]

**Step 5**

Find ASP in your application on main panel(under IIS section)

[image]

**Step 6**

Right click on **ASP** find **Enable Parent Path** (under Behavior).
Then make it value as **True**

[image]

**Step 7**

Then go to main panel in your IIS manger tool , under sites find your deployed site.Then right click it .Find explore go to location of that release folder

[image]

**Step 8**

Right click on that folder go to properties then give permission to relevant users

[image]

After above changes my problem solved hope yours too.

Answer (score 0):

**file exitension**

I have the same problem. in my code behind, there are two cases only for the file extension, the .xls and .xlsx.  please try to add .XLS and .XLSX

in short,  just add two upper case on that two