# Run Oracle query onClick of button

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have an aspx page in that I have a button.

Now what I want it,  i want to write a query on the onclick of the button. How to to that. ?

Here is my code:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Broker Rating" 
        Width="145px" onclick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

Also see my C# code:-

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // how to write the query
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried like below, but I am getting error as

> connection property has not been initialized

Here is my code:-

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string strConnString = "";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OracleConn"]);
    string strQuery = "SELECT ab.broker_id,CASE WHEN SYSDATE - la.creation_date <= 180 THEN 'A' WHEN SYSDATE - cef_dt <= 30 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C'END rating " +
                      "FROM xxacl_pn_new_cha_part ab,xxacl_pn_lease_det ld,xxacl_pn_leases_all la,xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v ce " +
                      "WHERE ab.broker_id = ld.broker_id AND ld.booking_no = la.booking_no AND ab.broker_id = ce.broker_id";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            //update message to be displayed here   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://someictstuff.blogspot.in/2013/07/aspnet-how-to-execute-query-to-oracle.html

Comment: @Neel: sir can you post only the relevant info here,as it's in vb and whole connectionstring is mentioned. **I want to keep short and simple**

Comment: @Neel: Please see my update and help if possible..!

Comment: check your web.config file for ConnectionString properly coded or not?

Comment: @RojalinSahoo: yes it is properly coded..!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007786/how-to-fix-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized  follow this may help you.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo: now it went to _finally_ block. what should I do to display succesful message and in which block ??

Comment: use break point and check it that it execute while block if yes then use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "", "alert('update done');", true); `

Comment: @RojalinSahoo: its going in finally block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89445/discussion-between-rojalin-sahoo-and-nadeem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
```

... to these two lines:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery, conn);
```

and for your connection string:

```
var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: getting error as `the best overloaded method has some invalid arguments`

Comment: still getting error as `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`

Comment: it is because you are not assigning connection string properly

Comment: any other way to assign it ?? I have used the default way to assign it..!

Comment: i used like this `OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString);`  now it didn't gaved me error, it went into _finally_ block. What I want is on succesfull debug i want to display message that it has been succesfully submitted

Comment: yes, there was some silly mistake related to the DB.